# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly even after trying conversion and formatting

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple histogram in the shell to give a dictionary with keys which have their values as the probability of the key being chosen if the keys were selected at random. I used formatting which for some reason didn't work. I also did the explicit conversion as usual by using the str() function but i still got the same error. I used a for loop and for some reason it worked when the probability of the key was 1 but it gave an error afterwards.

This is the debug window:

```
def histogram(word):
    'takes a word and returns an histogram of it'
    d = dict()
    for letter in word:`enter code here`
        d[letter] = d.get(letter,0) + 1 
    return (d)

>>> h = histogram('mississipi')
>>> print (h)
{'i': 4, 'p': 1, 's': 4, 'm': 1}
```

This part worked fine but then the problem surfaced

```
def histogram(word):
    'takes a word and returns an histogram of it'
    d = dict()
    for letter in word:
        d[letter] = '{}/{}'.format((d.get(letter,0) + 1),len(word))
    return d

>>> print (histogram('mississippi'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    print (histogram('mississippi'))
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 5, in histogram
    d[letter] = '{}/{}'.format((d.get(letter,0) + 1),len(word))
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

```
def histogram(word):
    'takes a word and returns an histogram of it'
    d = dict()
    for letter in word:
        d[letter] = str(d.get(letter,0) + 1) + '/' + str(len(word))
    return d

>>> print (histogram('mississippi'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    print (histogram('mississippi'))
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 5, in histogram
    d[letter] = str(d.get(letter,0) + 1) + '/' + str(len(word))
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

After this it seemed to work but still showed error

```
def histogram(word):
    'takes a word and returns an histogram of it'
    d = dict()
    for letter in word:
        d[letter] = str(d.get(letter,0) + 1) + '/' + str(len(word))
        print (d)

>>> print (histogram('mississippi'))
{'m': '1/11'}
{'m': '1/11', 'i': '1/11'}
{'s': '1/11', 'm': '1/11', 'i': '1/11'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    print (histogram('mississippi'))
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 5, in histogram
    d[letter] = str(d.get(letter,0) + 1) + '/' + str(len(word))
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: '1/11' is a string, everything that is surrounded by quotes is a string. What you want isn't `'{}/{}'.format(a,b)` but simply `a/b`

Comment: `d.get(letter,0)` returns a string, you can't add 1 to that.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing *strings* into your dictionary, and then try to add 1 to the value of the string.

Separate the counting and the string formatting; **first** create counts, then produce the final dictionary with your strings:

```
def histogram(word):
    d = {}
    # create counts
    for letter in word:
        d[letter] = d.get(letter, 0) + 1
    # produce a dictionary with count/len strings
    return {l: '{}/{}'.format(c, len(word)) for l, c in d.items()}
```

You may want to look at [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to replace your letter-counting loop:

```
from collections import Counter

def histogram(word):
    d = Counter(word)
    return {l: '{}/{}'.format(c, len(word)) for l, c in d.items()}
```

Comment: I don't get why you would want strings rather than actual numbers for the values of an histogram ...

Comment: @jadsq: why not ask that on the question then?